# Can I use Google Ad Manager to place and manage my own ads on all of my sites?

Tags: google-ad-manager

I have 30 different websites and I want to place a single ad across all of the sites. Is it possible to use Google ad manager so in the future I can change the ad on google ad manager and have them change universally on all my sites?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the main role of an ad server to enables you to :

- manage your inventory (create sites / placements...etc)
- manage your deliveries (campaigns / line items / creatives...etc)

You need to check the online ressources to understang how it works, starting with [this](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/6022000?hl=en).